# Pass xml from controller to js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

What I'm going to achive on UI. I have a table of objects and one parameter of the object is xml string. When I click by link for some row there should open pop-up with formatted xml.
So, I've tried to pass xml string to View with viewmodel and then put it to data attribute of a link. Read data attribute with js and put it to pop-up. I use bootstrap modal-dialog. So it looks smth like this:

```
<a class="open-xml" data-toggle="modal" data-xmlstring="@modal.Xml">Open xml</a>
```

and in js:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-xml", function() {
        var responseXml = $(this).data('xmlstring');
        $("#xml-viewer").find("textarea").text(responseXml);
    }
);
```

but it show only first word.
I've tried to parse it to json and encode it in js but it still doesn't work for me. Maybe you have another solution for it, or working example of current?

Answer (score 0):

To set value of textarea use `val()`

```
$("#xml-viewer").find("textarea").val(responseXml);
```

If this isn't working you would probably do better to retrieve the xml as text using ajax and set value using the response text

Comment: The problem is that when I get xml from data

var responseXml = $(this).data('xmlstring');

I receive only first word of xml because it's separated with xml formatting

Comment: browser probably not liking the xml in the dom like that. Would use ajax to get it instead

Comment: What is purpose of xml in textarea anyway? If editing there would be better UI methods for doing it

Comment: It's just a way to represent it and It could be some another control. The main problem is to pass xml to js.

Comment: But what do you mean by "retrieve the xml as text using ajax and set value using the response text"?

Comment: something like `$.get('path/to/xml', function(data){ $("#xml-viewer").find("textarea").val(data);},'text')`

Comment: Put url needed in data attribute instead of the actual xml

Comment: But I've already pass xml from controller to view with viewmodel and in this case I need some extra call to another method from controller that receive me xml from DB again for certain object when I click on link?
Am I right that 'path/to/xml' it should be controller method that receive to me xml for some object?

Comment: Yes...that would be the idea. Same click handler...different code and a server endpoint to send just the xml needed

Comment: But the idea is to get data when page is loaded and then just render it in pop-up without extracall and waiting time to get xml data again

Comment: You could also pass it to JavaScript variable as  string and not inject it into the DOM. Ajax doesn't take long though

Comment: In script tag `var xml ='@modal.Xml';`. Might have to escape the xml string

Comment: Interesting. But I have a list of objects on the page so I can't have only one variable xml. How should I create script tag for each object on the page?

Comment: could put all the strings into one object with property names referenced in the data attributes. Ajax would still be much cleaner and does not take long

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Add another div with displayed none in a link with

```
@model.Xml
```

. And by the click get this peace of html and put it to the pop-up with js.
So I transfer to js not xml, string or json but formatted html.